# How to alert users when connection is gone using Offline.js

Tags: javascript, offline, offlineapps, offline-mode

I'm trying to alert users when they are offline, and show a simple message. I'm using Offline.js as a library ([Offline.js website](http://github.hubspot.com/offline/docs/welcome/)).

I want to write JS and not use [Eager](https://eager.io) to install it automatically.

Here is what I wrote, but it doesn't seem to be working. Can someone help me with more details?

I couldn't find a sample with code on the library website.

```
Offline.options = {checkOnLoad: true, checks: {image: {url: 'http://www.vitaminedz.com/photos/49/02-49565-front-de-mer-a-oran.jpg'}, active: 'image'}}

Offline.check();
Offline.on('up', alert('up'));
Offline.on('down',alert('down'));
```

[JSFiddle Code + DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/genius50/1za322L2/)

Comment: Note that github doesn't let you link to files from jsfiddle like that - it serves them with a `text/plain` mime type, so your fiddle is (currently) non-functional.

Answer (score 7):

Your handlers are not set properly. It should be like this:

```
alert(Offline.check());
Offline.on('up', function() {
    alert('up');
});
Offline.on('down', function() {
    alert('down')
});
```

Comment: Offline.js not only trigger these messages but re-initiate the ajax that was broke during the connection broke. But after success methods of such Ajax are not triggered. How to trigger them?

Answer (score 0):

After Linking Your js and css theme of the offline you then add these code.

```
<script type="text/">
var run = function(){
if (Offline.state === 'up')
Offline.check();
}
 setInterval(run, 1000);
</script>
```

NOTE: It Will Work only if you call your jquery.js code above it.